# Selenium - parsing a page takes too long

Tags: python, parsing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

I work with Selenium in Python 2.7. I get that loading a page and similar thing takes far longer than raw requests because it simulates everything including JS etc.

The thing I don't understand is that parsing of already loaded page takes too long.

Everytime when page is loaded, I find all tags meeting some condition (about 30 div tags) and then I put each tag as an attribute to parsing function. For parsing I'm using css_selectors and similar methods like: `on.find_element_by_css_selector("div.carrier p").text`

As far as I understand, when tha page is loaded, the source code of this page is saved in my RAM or anywhere else so parsing should be done in miliseconds.

EDIT: I bet that parsing the same source code using BeautifulSoup would be more than 10 times faster but I don't understand why.

Do you have any explanation? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*These are different tools for different purposes*. `Selenium` is a browser automation tool that has a rich set of techniques to locate elements. `BeautifulSoup` is an HTML parser. When you find an element with `Selenium` - this is not an HTML parsing. In other words, `driver.find_element_by_id("myid")` and `soup.find(id="myid")` are very different things.

When you ask selenium to find an element, say, using `find_element_by_css_selector()`, there is an [HTTP request](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py#350) being sent to `/session/$sessionId/element` endpoint by the [JSON wire protocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol). Then, your selenium python client would receive a response and return you a `WebElement` instance if everything went without errors. You can think of it as a real-time/dynamic thing, you are getting a real Web Element that is "living" in a browser, you can control and interact with it.

With `BeautifulSoup`, once you download the page source, there is no network component anymore, no real-time interaction with a page and the element, there is only HTML parsing involved.

---

In practice, if you are doing web-scraping and you need a real browser to execute javascript and handle AJAX, and you are doing a complex HTML parsing afterwards, it would make sense to get the desired `.page_source` and feed it to `BeautifulSoup`, or, even better in terms of speed - `lxml.html`.

Note that, in cases like this, usually there is no need for the complete HTML source of the page. To make the HTML parsing faster, you can feed an "inner" or "outer" HTML of the page block containing the desired data to the html parser of the choice. For example:

```
container = driver.find_element_by_id("container").getAttribute("outerHTML")
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(container, "lxml")
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So it doesn't sending requests to real web page in this case?

Comment: @Milan every `find_element_by_*` call would result into an HTTP interaction between your selenium python client, (selenium server) and a webdriver. This is what actually makes it slow. I've extended the explanation a bit. Hope it makes things clearer. Thanks, good question!